# Bootstrap Footer resizing up causing content of page to be covered

Tags: html, css, resize, bootstrap-4, footer

I have a bootstrap footer which I set to position:absolute so that it stays at the bottom of the page at all times (my page being a single-page website).

Problem: when I re-size the screen width and hit the ~980px mark, the footer height resizes upwards in height to cover most of the content of the page (in my case a login panel). This is annoying: what should happen is that it should resize downwards, allowing for the user to keep on seeing the login panel.

Potential non-solutions: I've tried position:relative but this will leave the footer hanging in the middle of page.

```
 <body style="height:100%;min-height:100%">

 <footer class="page-footer font-small indigo" style="position:absolute;right: 0;bottom: 0;left: 0;">
<div class="container text-center text-md-left">
  <div class="row" id="footer">
    <div class="col-md-3 mx-auto">
      <h5 class="font-weight-bold text-uppercase mt-3 mb-4">Explore</h5>
      <ul class="list-unstyled">
        <li>
          <a href="#!">Link 1</a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="#!">Link 2</a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="#!">Link 3</a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="#!">Link 4</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
<div class="col-md-3 mx-auto">
      <h5 class="font-weight-bold text-uppercase mt-3 mb-4">About us</h5>
      <ul class="list-unstyled">
        <li>
          <a href="#!">About us</a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="#!">Trust and safety</a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="#!">Help and support</a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="#!">Contact</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>

    <div class="col-md-3 mx-auto">
      <h5 class="font-weight-bold text-uppercase mt-3 mb-4">How does it work?</h5>
      <ul class="list-unstyled">
        <li>
          <a href="#!">Link 1</a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="#!">Link 2</a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="#!"></a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="#!"></a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>

    <div class="col-md-3 mx-auto">
      <h5 class="font-weight-bold text-uppercase mt-3 mb-4">Links</h5>
      <ul class="list-unstyled">
        <li>
          <a href="#!">Link 1</a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="#!">Link 2</a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="#!">Link 3</a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="#!">Link 4</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
</footer>

</body>
```

Comment: Can you change "text-md-left" to "text-sm-left" and col-md-3 to col-sm-3" or better to "col-md-3 col-sm-12" or something. Can't repruduce you error, but just some ideas

Comment: Did not work i'm afraid

Comment: see fine to me!! i don't see any glitches

Comment: Hi @DeepakVerma , I edited the above saying that there are 4 columns. This is why it resizes up, you see?

Comment: @DeepakVerma try with the edited code now

Comment: this is happening because you have defined col-md to adjust columns there styles are applicable to md and higher and for sm each column then expand to 12 row which makes it grow

Answer (score 0):

Try to use [breakpoints](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/layout/overview/#responsive-breakpoints).

```
@media (min-width: 992px){
    .page-footer{
        position:absolute;
        right: 0;
        bottom: 0;
        left: 0;
    }
}
```

But you need to remove footer style from html and create `.css` file to use this code (or place it into `<style>` tag).